# Convert IOrderedEnumerable back to Custom List<T>

Tags: c#

How do I convert

`public class MyCustomList: List<MyCustomList>`

back to `MyCustomList` after ordering?

`myCustomListObject = myCustomListObject.OrderBy(...);`

I tried `.ToList() as myCustomListObject` which returns null. What should I do?

Comment: @Anirudha: `AsEnumerable()` doesn't return an instance of the OP's type `MyCustomList` any more than any other `Enumerable` extension method such as `OrderBy` or `ToList`.

Comment: Add a constructor to your class that takes  a `List<MyCustomList>`, then you can use it to create an instance from `myCustomListObject.OrderBy(...).ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyCustomList: List<MyCustomList>
{
  //stuff you already have here, including your current constructors
  public MyCustomList(IEnumerable<MyCustomList> source)
  {
    //something here that (perhaps after using `this` to call
    //one of the existing constructors, loads all of the items
    //in source into it. There may be optimisations available
    //in particular cases, as a bonus.
  }
}
```

If you really want to be able to do something like the `ToList()` style, then you can add:

```
public static class MyBigOClassOHelpfulStaticMethods //maybe pick a better name
{
  public static MyCustomList ToMyCustomList(this IEnumerable<MyCustomList> source)
  {
    return new MyCustomList(source);
  }
}
```

Which isn't far off how `ToList()` works.

All this said though, if you are going to be often writing over the first `MyCustomList` with the new one, then there'd be something to gain by calling `Sort` instead of `OrderBy`, as `Sort` will sort the list in-place.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that ToList() will return a List.  You cannot convert it to a MyCustomList just like you cannot convert another object some somthing that it isnt.

```
List<string> result = myCustomListObject.OrderBy(...).ToList();
```

If you really need a MyCustomListObject you should create a constructor that accepts a explicit cast operation.

If MyCustomList is just another name for List<string> you could use:

```
using MyCustomList = List<string>;
```

Then it will work like you want it to.

Comment: Why do you assume `MyCustomList` has anything to do with a string list? It seems to be a recursive list currently.

Comment: Sorry, read it as public class MyCustomList: List<string>, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `OrderBy` simply is no instance of `MyCustomList`, and neither is the return value of `ToList`. Therefore, you *cannot* cast it to `MyCustomList`.

The only options you have are:

- You create a new instance of `MyCustomList` and add the elements returned by `OrderBy`.
- You replace the current contentes of your `MyCustomList` instance with the elements returned by `OrderBy`.

Without knowing more about your `MyCustomList` class, it is impossible to tell more. As it inherits from `List<MyCustomList>`, however, it can be assumed that both of the above options are feasible.

Comment: Well that sucks!  In this case I am ok converting back to a `List<MyCustomClass>` so I will just take that then.  It is strange to have a List of a List just to appease the compiler, but it works.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I'm not sure what you mean by *have a List of a List just to appease the compiler* and I suspect something about your class design is unnecessarily complex. As it is now, I don't see anything in your question that would make you have a list of a list other than your own decision to have a list of lists (namely of type `MyCustomList`).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with O. R. Mapper in that, without knowing more about MyCustomList, it's hard to answer.  But you could just do something simple like this (again, without knowing more, this may now work):

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new MyList() { new Stuff() { ugg = "z" }, new Stuff() { ugg = "b" } };

    var myOrderedList = list.OrderBy(s => s.ugg);

    myOrderedList.ToList().Dump();

    var list2 = new MyList();
    list2.AddRange(myOrderedList);
    list2.GetType().Name.Dump();
}

public class Stuff{
    public string ugg {get;set;}
}
// Define other methods and classes here
public class MyList : List<Stuff>{
}
```

I use LinqPad to display the contents and type names using the `Dump()` extension method.